# Can I diff HTML by its semantic or structure?

Tags: html, diff

For example, I want the following to be considered same.

```
<div id="div" class="txt">
   Foo bar
</div>
```

and

```
<div   class="txt"                          id="div"          >Foo bar</div>
```

I have searched with diff and html, I found diff tool show it's diff result in HTML.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: these two codesnippets should have no diff in the rendered html (perhaps having an additional whitespace-textnode)so a difftool comparing the diff-results should be pretty much be the thing you are looking for?

Comment: @Christoph thank you. I agree with you.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs "Why" isn't really relevant, I think the point is that the OP wants to compare structure and ignore irrelevant representational artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a tool to do this at http://prettydiff.com/ but be sure to select HTML from the language list, because the auto detection will attempt to treat your HTML code as XML.

Comment: I already tried prettydiff. It`s good at space handling, but attribute order is not. I tested again with "<p id="a" class="b"></p>" and "<p class="b" id="a">". If prettydiff is ignore attribute order, it will be perfect to me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I will work this change into the application.

Comment: @Solip could you check out your suggestion in a beta update to see the tool does what you need:  http://prettydiff.com/testlocation/

Comment: It seems work same as expected. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: I wanted to compare the structure ignoring all content. Unfortunately I couldn't get that to work with the option "ignore content".